# How to view more than 10 rows for a table in RStudio Notebook

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

I'm using RStudio's R Notebook and would like to view 12 rows in my table, rather than have it limited to 10. I know you can click through to see the last two but I'd like to show all 12.

I have tried:

```
head(table_name, 12)
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

thanks!

[image: example table showing only 10 or the 12 rows]

Answer (score 0):

Options with {knitr} or {DT}:

With {knitr}

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(head(iris, 12))
```
````

Gives you:

[image]

Or with {DT}:

````
```{r dt}

library(DT)
datatable(head(iris, 12),  options = list(pageLength = 12))
```
````

[image]